# Retrieving the FirstName, LastName and Department when using the REST API and calling SiteUsers

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I normally use `ClientContext` to connect to SharePoint and use `SiteUserInfoList` to retrieve the list of SharePoint users. (I need to copy the data into an SQL Server database.) Disappointingly, this does not return all users in SharePoint. Specifically I am missing users that originate from another company; most likely there's some kind of security setting that prevents my user from seeing their data.

However, when I retrieve one of the lists I require, "Applications", I do get entries where these missing users are referenced, e.g. one of them is a `DTSupplyAccountable` of an Application. I only get a SharePoint ID, e.g. 265, and since I don't have a user with that ID I lack vital data about this Application.

Our SharePoint support recommended that I use the REST API instead to retrieve the data I need. Since there is no budget (or time) to rewrite the entire application, I've decided to use the REST API only to "plug the holes".

I was pleased to discover that calling `_api/Web/SiteUsers` gives me a far more complete list than `SiteUserInfoList` (see above). Yet this solution is imperfect: the resulting dataset lacks several properties I need:

- FirstName
- LastName
- Department

Admittedly, I can retrieve these by calling `_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Applications')/items(7)?$select=DTSupplyAccountable/Id,DTSupplyAccountable/FirstName,DTSupplyAccountable/LastName,DTSupplyAccountable/Department,DTSupplyAccountable/Title,*&$expand=
DTSupplyAccountable`, but considering that I need to do this for dozens of users and considering the "inelegance" of this solution, I would much rather find another way to do this.

Is there any possibility that I can add parameters to `SiteUsers` to retrieve the missing properties?

Comment: Do you want to get all users who are added to a particular site collection or all user in your farm?

Comment: Preferably all users. Right now the issue is with the list Applications, but that is a starting point where other data links to, so ideally I would get all of the relevant properties of all of the users.

Comment: How are the other company users added to the site? Directly or through any AD group?

Comment: @Unnie I don't know. SharePoint devs are a different department. I'm just importing data into a SQL Server table.

Answer (score 0):

Endpoint *http://siteurl/_api/web/siteusers* will return you all users who are added to that site,But it will not give you extra properties of the users like **Department**. SiteUserInfoList will have only those users who are added directly into the site and not through any AD group.

Alternately after getting list of users from SiteUsers you can query user profile for each user to get their additional properties. See this [blog](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html) on retrieving properties from user profile.

Comment: I have seen that blog post, but I can't get it to work.  User with ID 265 has `<d:LoginName>i:0#.w|msnet\qqz7500</d:LoginName>` but `/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='i:0#.w|msnet\qqz7500'` does not work.

Comment: Don't user `i:0#.w|`. Just use domain\user `(accountName=@v,propertyName='LastName')?@v='domain\username'`